# `igraph` and probability of stop at vertex

Tags: r, graph-algorithm, igraph, markov-chains

**How i can generate probabilities of stop at random walk on given vertex in the efficient way using package `igraph`?**

```
require(igraph)
require(data.table)
g <- make_ring(10, directed = TRUE) %u% make_star(11, center = 11) + edge(11, 1)
E(g)$weight <- runif(ecount(g))
plot(g,edge.label=round(E(g)$weight,2))
w <- random_walk(g, start = c(1), steps = 121, mode = "out")
table(w)
wdt <- as.data.table(table(w))
wdt[, wdt$N/sum(wdt$N)]
```

[image: Graph]

Gives output of proportions for a vertex out of total

```
> wdt[, wdt$N/sum(wdt$N)]
 [1] 0.338842975 0.157024793 0.066115702 0.033057851 0.024793388 0.016528926
 [7] 0.016528926 0.008264463 0.008264463 0.330578512
```

The problem with such approach, that in fact i just make one particular path on graph with `random_walk` and then calculate proportion to see probability. I would like to avoid performing computationally expensive random walk here with multiple simulations so it converges.

**Example**
It is possible with package `markovchain`

```
    ma_transitionProbs <- prop.table(as.matrix(get.adjacency(g, attr="weight")),1)
    library(markovchain)
    tmA <- ma_transitionProbs
    dtmcA <- new("markovchain",transitionMatrix= tmA ,
        name="MarkovChain A") #create the DTMC
    dtmcA
    initialState <- c(1,rep(0, 10))
    steps <- 4
    finalState<-initialState*dtmcA^steps #using power operator
    finalState
```

Comment: I dont' see how having your data in igraph is relevant here. You have a set of transition probabilities. This is really a stochastic process problem, not a programming one. This question seems a better for for [stats.se] where statistical problems belong. It's not clear to me what the specific programming question is here.

Comment: Question is about how to get random walk with `igraph` package. How to do it other ways, i know pretty well. I will delete formulas not to confuse people.

Comment: What statistical method do you want to use to estimate these probabilities? The igraph package doesn't have methods for stochastic processes.

Comment: @MrFlick this is doubtful, if `random_walk` function is there, then what is it? It is a stochastic process! Btw `page_rank` is also present there, which provides converging probabilities.

Comment: But `random_walk` doesn't use probabilities at all. It just jumps along connected vertices. If you've already read all the functions available in igraph, it should be clear that this functionality isn't there.